# ngx-mat-select-search - placeholderlabel, noEntriesFoundLabel is not appearing while searching

Tags: angular, select, angular-material, autocomplete

I am trying to change the `placeholderlabel` and `noentriesfoundlabel` for ngx-mat-select-search package. It is not working.

This is my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="search-field-dropdown" appearance="none">
  <mat-select
    formControlName="country"
    class="matdropdownCustom"
    placeholder="Country"
    placeholderLabel="Find country..."
    noEntriesFoundLabel="'no matching country found'"
  >
    <mat-option>
      <ngx-mat-select-search
        [formControl]="countryFilterCtrl"
      ></ngx-mat-select-search>
    </mat-option>

    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option1 of filteredCountriesList | async" 
      [value]="option1.name"
      >
        {{ option1.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **place both `placeholderLabel` and `noEntriesFoundLabel` for `ngx-mat-select-search` element**, not `mat-select` element.

```
<ngx-mat-select-search
    [formControl]="countryFilterCtrl"
    placeholderLabel="Find country..."
    noEntriesFoundLabel="'no matching country found'"
></ngx-mat-select-search>
```

---

### References

[NgxMatSelectSearch Label section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search)

Comment: This worked nicely!